# Clickhouse MaterializedView not getting populated

Tags: clickhouse, materialized-views

I'm trying to create a Materialized view on Clickhouse which is a join on two other tables. The definitions for the tables are shown below:

```
CREATE TABLE t1(tId String, tName String, timestamp DateTime) ENGINE = MergeTree ORDER BY timestamp;
CREATE TABLE t2(sId String, sName String, sLength Int64, timestamp DateTime) ENGINE = MergeTree ORDER BY timestamp; 


CREATE TABLE jt (`timestamp` DateTime,`tId` String CODEC(ZSTD(1)),`sName` String,`sLength` Int64,`tName` String) ENGINE = MergeTree PARTITION BY toDate(timestamp) ORDER BY timestamp;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW jt_mv TO jt (`timestamp` DateTime,`tId` String CODEC(ZSTD(1)), `sName` String,`sLength` Int64,`tName` String ) AS SELECT t1.timestamp AS timestamp, t1.tId AS tId, t1.tName AS tName, t2.sName AS sName, t2.sLength AS sLength FROM (SELECT timestamp,tId,tName FROM t1 ) AS t1 INNER JOIN (SELECT tId, sName, sLength, timestamp FROM t2) AS t2 ON t1.tId = t2.tId
```

All tables and view are created correctly, and as expected there's no data in any tables. Now I insert data into the t1 and t2 tables

```
insert into t1 values ('1', 'First', NOW());
insert into t1 values ('2', 'Second', NOW());
insert into t2 values ('1', 'First 1', 5, NOW());
insert into t2 values ('1', 'First 2', 5, NOW());
insert into t2 values ('2', 'Second 1', 10, NOW());
```

This inserts data into `t1` and `t2` correctly, but when I look at the materialized view, there's no data in it.

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM t1

2 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.005 sec.

SELECT count(*)
FROM t2

3 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.006 sec.

SELECT count(*)
FROM jt

0 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.004 sec.


SELECT count(*)
FROM jt_mv

0 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.003 sec.
```

I'm unsure why this is the case. Am I missing something with how MVs work in Clickhouse? Can anyone help or point me to the documentation? I've been [following this](https://altinity.com/blog/clickhouse-materialized-views-illuminated-part-2), but it's not working with the join MV.

Comment: as Expected MatView is a trigger on insert into the most left table in the from section.

Comment: https://den-crane.github.io/Everything_you_should_know_about_materialized_views_commented.pdf

Comment: https://clickhouse.com/blog/using-materialized-views-in-clickhouse

Comment: @DennyCrane This was very helpful. Figured out the issue I had. Basically the way I set up the MV, it's a trigger-on-insert on t1, which doesn't have any data because the data for the join in t2 was coming in in subsequent queries.

Can you please post your reply as an answer so I can accept it as the answer? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MatView is an on insert trigger, it's triggered by insertion into the most left table (in the from section).

https://den-crane.github.io/Everything_you_should_know_about_materialized_views_commented.pdf

https://clickhouse.com/blog/using-materialized-views-in-clickhouse

https://youtu.be/QDAJTKZT8y4

https://kb.altinity.com/altinity-kb-schema-design/materialized-views/